# Can someone explain the difference between node / heroku / AWS / Firebase/ Apache?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, apache, heroku

I know this question is all over the place but i'm new to the back end and I'm trying to understand web servers. With Node, you can create a server and deploy it to Heroku. But why create a server in Node if you are using the servers with Heroku? Is Heroku the same as AWS and Firebase in terms of what they do? And what is Apache? Thank you.

Comment: Node is a wrapper for the V8 JS engine and includes an API to access the machine it is running on. You can use it with express js for example to serve http requests. Apache and NGINX on the over hand are complete webserver solutions. They usually use PHP together with MySQL. Heroku, AWS and Firebase are all cloud services, they basically just a computer somewhere else running your application. I recommend you start with Heroku, it got easy solutions for everything and a free hobby dino (that's how they call the containers your apps are running in on the server). AWS and Firebase are complex.

Answer (score 2):

Node is a tool/software written in c++, that uses browser's V8 engine to run JS code on your computer OUTSIDE browser. So it can be used to develop server aplications with JavaScript.

Heroku is a platform that your server application can be deployed to to make it accessible from the web.

Firebase is a set of tools to run serverless applications, it provides nosql database, file storage, server for static files to store your frontend application etc

Apache is a software to make static files accessible from the web on your machine. Similar to NGINX.

AWS is a huge platform, that can provide you with all kinds of stuff: databases/servers/cloud functions/analytics etc. Similar to gCloud platform.